# Including resource dictionary in UserControl.Resources fails to compile

Tags: wpf, parsing, xaml

I have a custom control that I want to apply some styles from a resource dictionary in another project. For some reason, adding resources in the `UserControl.Resources` fails, however placing it in the `Grid.Resources` succeeds;

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Name.Space.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="UserControlResources">
            <!--Putting it here fails-->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="GridResources">
                <!--Putting it here succeeds-->
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <!--Control XAML-->

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

I get an error "The name 'IntializeComponent' does not exist in the current context". However, looking at the autogenerated MyUserControl.g.i.cs file, hey presto; there it is. What am I doing wrong? What is the difference between these two declarations?

Thanks, Sterren

Comment: Can you even give a key to a resource dictionary?

Comment: @Andy - Yes, if I compile the code with only the Grid.Resources element, it succeeds.

Comment: I've never seen anyone do it this way. Why not just specify it as a `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` in an App.xaml like normal? Or if it's implicit Styles not used elsewhere, enter them directly in your App.xaml/Generic or to the UC Resources itself?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, perhaps I am approaching this particular task incorrectly. However, my question isn't really about "Is what I am doing good practice", it is more "why does what I do fail and give a compiler error". This is what I don't understand.